# Memory Management in loops

Tags: iphone, objective-c, loops, memory-leaks

A `UINavigationController` is pushing a `UIViewController` when clicking on an entry of a table. The appearing view creates a lot of `UILabels` by a loop like this:

```
for(i=0, i < 50, i++)
{
    pointer = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFram:CGRectMake(i, 5, 5, 5)];
    pointer.text = ...;
    ...
    [scrollView addSubView:pointer];
    [pointer release];
}
```

How can i free all the memory when the view disappears? isn´t that a problem, that the pointer "pointer" points only to the last `UILabel`? and to the other `UILabels` there are no more pointer?
Because the views are pushed very slowly after having loaded some of them before.

Answer (score 2):

You should make UILabel *pointer a local variable in this loop. To make it clear that you don't need the pointer somewhere else, because you don't.

You retain (alloc) them, the scrollView retains them, you release them. And when the scrollview gets released it will release the UILabels. All of them.

Everything is fine.

Comment: all right... releasing the scrollView... i am such a dummy :) thx for the really fast answers!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to free all the UILabels manually. You're already releasing them in a loop. So to handle memory properly just make sure that scrollView is released properly.